# Including one list component and excluding all other components repeatedly in R

Tags: r, loops, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a list of values. I would like to use the first value in one portion of a function and use the remaining values in a separate part of the function. Then, I would like to use the second value from the list in one portion of the function and use the remaining values (including the first value) in another part of the function.

The following is not real code since I have excluded some function inputs, but it shows what I am trying to do:

```
group <- c(1, 3, 4, 5, 9) #the complete group 
#It is important to note that these values are not continuous. They are distinct values. 


#include 1st unit of the list group as treatment and then use
#the remaining values as controls 

controls_not2 <- c(3, 4, 5, 9)
df1 <- dataprep(treatment = 1, controls = controls_not1) 
gaps.plot(dataprep = df1) 


#use the 2nd unit from the list as the treatment and use
#the remaining values as controls 

controls_not2 <- c(1, 4, 5, 9)
df2 <- dataprep(treatment = 3, controls = controls_not3) 
gaps.plot(dataprep = df3)
```

In the full list, I have about 50 values. Is there a way for me to iterate over all these values in the way I have shown above?

---

Here is some additional information.

Packages used:

```
library(tidyverse) 
library(synth)
```

Here is an example of what the full code looks like to create a single graph.

treatment.identifier is equivalent to what I have as treatment in the simple example above. controls.identifier is equivalent to what I have as controls in the example above.

```
dataprep.out1 <- dataprep(foo = as.data.frame(df), 
                         predictors = predictors1, 
                         predictors.op = "mean", 
                         special.predictors = NULL, 
                         dependent = "logfatalitiespercapita", 
                         unit.variable = "state", 
                         time.variable = "year", 
                     treatment.identifier = "99", 
                     controls.identifier = controlstates, 
                     time.predictors.prior = c(1981:1985), 
                     time.optimize.ssr = c(1981:1985), #check on these years
                     time.plot = 1981:2003, 
                     unit.names.variable = "statenames") 

#identifying weights that create the best possible synthetic control unit for the treated 
synth.out1 <- synth(dataprep.out1)

#graph
spec1 <- gaps.plot(dataprep.res = dataprep.out1, synth.res = synth.out1, Xlab = c("Year"), Ylab = c("Gap"))
```

Comment: @akrun I have added them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To store the results in a list, this ignores what the values are and uses 1:50 as the index

```
library(purrr)
result <- map(1:50, ~{ #replace 50 with the length of your list
df <- dataprep(treatment = group[[.x]], controls = group[[-.x]])
 gaps.plot(dataprep = df)})
```

---

This is a similar solution inspired by the solution above.

```
newfunction <- function(x) {
    df <- dataprep(treatment = group[x], controls = group[-x])
     gaps.plot(dataprep = df)
}

graphs <- lapply(group, newfunction)
```

Comment: Is there supposed to be another bracket to close the initial bracket?

Comment: What does the .x mean? Did you define that anywhere? It is not working when I try to run it myself.

Comment: when using the `purrr` package .x is a pronoun you can use with map and ~{}, think of it like function(.x){}. What is the error you are getting? I tried to run your code and I don't have the object df

Comment: Rather than using map, I was able to get this approach to work by creating a function. list[[.x]] would not work, but list[x] and list[-x] did work in the function. I then used lapply.

Answer (score 0):

First a comment, you may not want to use 'list' as a vector name since list is a data type in R. You can subset the vector by referring to the index number. Example below.

list1 <- c(1, 3, 4, 5, 9) #the complete group

```
df1 <- dataprep(treatment = 1, controls = list1[c(1,3:length(list1))]) 
gaps.plot(dataprep = df1) 


#use the 2nd unit from the list as the treatment and use
#the remaining values as controls 

df2 <- dataprep(treatment = 3, controls = list1[c(2)]) 
gaps.plot(dataprep = df3)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)

myVec = 1:6

doSomething <- function(treatment, myVec){
  controls = myVec[! myVec == treatment]
  paste("Treatment:", treatment, "Controls:", paste(controls, collapse = "-"))
}
map_chr(myVec, ~ doSomething(.x, myVec))

[1] "Treatment: 1 Controls: 2-3-4-5-6" "Treatment: 2 Controls: 1-3-4-5-6" "Treatment: 3 Controls: 1-2-4-5-6"
[4] "Treatment: 4 Controls: 1-2-3-5-6" "Treatment: 5 Controls: 1-2-3-4-6" "Treatment: 6 Controls: 1-2-3-4-5"
```

Comment: This is closer to what I am asking about if you change myVec = 1:6 to myVec = as.vector(group). Then, it doesn't have to be 1 through 6 sequentially and can include whatever numbers are in the group object.